# Long lasting script prevents handling new requests

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a PHP script on my Apache web server, which starts another several hours running PHP script. Right after the long-lasting script is started no other PHP script requests are handled. The browser just hangs eternally.

The background script crawls other sites and gathers data from ones. Therefore it takes quite long time.

At the same time static pages are got without problems. Also at the same time any PHP script started locally on the server from bash are executed without problems.

CPU and RAM usage are low. In fact it's test server and my requests are only ones being handled.

I tried to decrease Apache processes in order to be able to trace all of them to see where requests are hung. But when I decreased amount of processes to 2 the problem has gone.

I found no errors neither in syslog nor in apache/error.log

What else can I check?

Comment: why do you have a PHP script running in the browser for several hours?

Comment: It doesn't run in browser. It runs on the server in the background. It's started from the script, which is called from the browser

Comment: what is the script doing?  that's going to be key to finding out why your browser requests aren't working.

Comment: The background script crawls other sites and gathers data from ones. Therefore it takes quite long time.

Answer (score 0):

Though I didn't find the reason of Apache hanging I have solved the task in a different way. 
I've set a schedule to run a script every 5 minutes. From web script I'm just creating a file with necessary parameters. Script check existence of the file and if it exists it reads its content and deletes to prevent further scheduled start.